# Determine on nsis if internet connection is available

Tags: nsis

How can I determine if is there available internet connection on my NSIS function?

I saw Intec plugin but I didn't find how to do that

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Dailer plugin for that.

Try this:

```
Dialer::GetConnectedState
Pop $1
```

if there is internet connection, $1 will be `online` either, it will be `offline`

Read more on:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Dialer/Dialer.txt

Answer (score 1):

According to [NSIS documentation](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Connect_to_the_internet) on Windows Vista and later it is recommended to use [`INetworkListManager::GetConnectivity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/netlistmgr/nf-netlistmgr-inetworklistmanager-getconnectivity) to check if Internet is connected.

Here is a function that uses recommended approach:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Function IsInternetConnected
    !define CLSID_NetworkListManager "{DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"
    !define IID_INetworkListManager "{DCB00000-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B}"
    !define CLSCTX_ALL 23

    Push $R0
    Push $R1
    Push $R2
    Push $R3
    Push $R9

    ; Result - is internet connected.
    StrCpy $R0 false

    SetPluginUnload alwaysoff

    System::Call "ole32::CoCreateInstance(g '${CLSID_NetworkListManager}', i 0, i ${CLSCTX_ALL}, g '${IID_INetworkListManager}', *i .R1) i .R9"
    IntCmp $R9 0 0 end

    ; INetworkListManager->GetConnectivity(NLM_CONNECTIVITY*)
    System::Call "$R1->13(*i .R2) i .R9"
    IntCmp $R9 0 0 end

    ; IUnknown->Release()    
    System::Call "$R1->2() i"

    ; Internet IPv4: NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV4_INTERNET = 64.
    IntOp $R3 $R2 & 64
    ${If} $R3 <> 0
        StrCpy $R0 true
        Goto end
    ${EndIf}

    ; Internet IPv6: NLM_CONNECTIVITY_IPV6_INTERNET = 1024.
    IntOp $R3 $R2 & 1024
    ${If} $R3 <> 0
        StrCpy $R0 true
        Goto end
    ${EndIf}

  end:
    SetPluginUnload manual

    Pop $R9
    Pop $R3
    Pop $R2
    Pop $R1

    Exch $R0
FunctionEnd
```

This is how to use this function:

```
!include "LogicLib.nsh"

Section
    Push $0

    Call IsInternetConnected
    Pop $0  

    ${If} $0 == false
        MessageBox MB_OK "Internet is not connected"
    ${Else}
        MessageBox MB_OK "Internet is connected"
    ${EndIf}

    Pop $0
SectionEnd
```

May be it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0):

```
            TESTAGIN:
            ClearErrors
            SetDetailsPrint both
DetailPrint "$(TEST_TEST)"
SetDetailsPrint none
            inetc::head /silent "http://www.msn.com" "$SYSDIR\test.txt"
            Pop $0 # return value = exit code, "OK" if OK
            ${If} $0 != OK
            GOTO Done
            ${Else}
            MessageBox MB_RETRYCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "$(TEST_INTERNET_CONNECTION)" IDRETRY TESTAGIN
            #quit
            ${EndIf}
            Done:
            SetDetailsPrint both
DetailPrint "$(TEST_OK)"
SetDetailsPrint none
            ClearErrors
```

Comment: Cool, but you could specify what is needed (http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in), i think a similar hack could be made using NSISDL plugin (for simple HTTP downloads) via download_quiet. And the latter is built in... http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Builtin_NSISdl_plug-in